# What should be the error in the mongodb pipeline query $project?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm pipeline my data in the mongodb collection but it will not returning any data to me the code is following:-

```
func GetLog(c *gin.Context) {
values := c.Query("value")
fmt.Println("value", values)
result := []bson.M{}
mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()
getCollection := mongoSession.DB(config.Database).C(config.LogCollection)
pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{ 
            bson.M{"$unwind": "$booking_details"},
                bson.M{"$project": bson.M{
                "role":1,
                "date":1,
                "idadress":1,
                "booking":1,
                "booking_values":bson.M{"$objectToArray":"$booking"},
            } },
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{
        "booking_values.v" : bson.RegEx{"(?i).*"+values+".*", "i"},
    }}, } )
fmt.Println(pipe)
err := pipe.All(&result)
fmt.Println(result)
}
```

In the values there will be `string` why this will not giving me any result. the data in mongodb is:

```
 {
  "_id": ObjectId("5b3d970398e9d099427896c3"),
  "role": "New Booking is there by abc",
  "date": "07/04/2018",
  "idaddress": "213.123.123.213",
  "booking": {
    "bedroom": 4,
    "bathroom": 6,
    "customer": "abc",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "provider": "provider1",
    "address": "brazil",
    "appt": "123456",
    "phone": "987654321"
 }
}
```

The struct is like given below:

```
 type Log struct {
Id              bson.ObjectId    `json:"_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Role              string         `json:"role" bson:"role"`
Date              string         `json:"date" bson:"date"`
IpAddress         string         `json:"idaddress" bson:"idaddress"`
Booking           interface{}    `json:"booking" bson:"booking"`
}
type Logs []Log
```

Comment: There is no `booking_details` field, and you try to `$unwind` it... so that will filter out all results.

Comment: @icza you are saying to `unwind` `Booking_values`

Comment: Is the sample of doc given coming from results of an unwind stage, or your base doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `pipe` code to the below code:-

```
pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{ 
                bson.M{"$project": bson.M{
                "role":1,
                "date":1,
                "idaddress":1,
                "booking":1,
                "booking_values":bson.M{"$objectToArray":"$booking"},
            } },
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{
        "booking_values.v" : bson.RegEx{"(?i).*"+values+".*", "i"},
    }}, } )
```

to you don't have any `booking_details` field as the **icza** said so you have to remove it and then run your go code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know this language, but :

- If you pass bson.M{"$unwind": "$booking_details"},  resulting docs will have "booking_details" fields,
- So you have to change

  ```
   "booking":1,
   "booking_values":bson.M{"$objectToArray":"$booking"},
  ```

by

```
     "booking_details":1,
     "booking_values":bson.M{"$objectToArray":"$booking_details"},
```